# Подключение нескольких скриптов

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Здрaвствуйте. Есть скрипт, который подключает `js` файл через 1 сек. после скролла. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как нужно переписать данный код, чтобы можно было подключать не один скрипт, а несколько (через их перечисление)?

В данный момент код выглядит следующим образом:

```
<script>
let ok = false;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  if (ok === false) {
    ok = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'folder/script-1.js';
      document.getElementById('includer').replaceWith(script);
    }, 1000)
  }
});
</script>
```

Необходимо чтобы было примерно следующее:

```
<script>
let ok = false;
window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  if (ok === false) {
    ok = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'folder/script-1.js';
      script.src = 'folder/script-2.js';
      script.src = 'folder/script-3.js';
      script.src = 'folder/script-4.js';
      script.src = 'folder/script-5.js';
      document.getElementById('includer').replaceWith(script);
    }, 1000)
  }
});
</script>
```

Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Так ?

```js
let ok = false;
let scripts = ['folder/script-1.js', 'folder/script-2.js', 'folder/script-3.js', 'folder/script-4.js', 'folder/script-5.js'];

window.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
  if (ok === false) {
    ok = true;
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Очистка тега с элементами
      document.getElementById('includer').innerHTML = '';
      // Заполнение тега новыми в цикле
      scripts.forEach(el => {
          let script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = el;
          document.getElementById('includer').append(script);
      });      
    }, 1000)
  }
});
```

Comment: Алексей, спасибо за ответ, Ваш код корректно работает - он помещает данные скрипты внутрь тега, однако затем они не исполняются. Предыдущий код (после своего выполнения) заменял тег `<div id="includer"></div>` скриптом `<script src="folder/script-1.js"></script>` и далее этот скрипт `script-1.js` немедленно исполнялся, а в данном случае они помещаются внутрь тега и ничего не происходит. Не знаете как заставить скрипты исполняться?

Comment: @caboke По идее должны работать. Можете попробовать 1 - писать не `document.getElementById('includer').append(script);`, а например `document.body.appendChild(script);`.  или в `head`. 2 - проверить вообще загружаются ли адекватно скрипты. Добавить в `script.onload=function() { console.log(\`скрипт ${el} загрузился\`) };` . Больше пока не могу сказать. Потому что у меня это всё отрабатывает) Специально только что проверил

Comment: Спасибо, благодарю за ответ.